# I want to merge all txt files to 1 txt files, but i get an error if a file is empty

Tags: vba

If i run it 1 time it works,the second time i runit the 2nd txt file is empty so the script stops running on this line:

```
strTxt = strTxt & txt.ReadAll
```

How can I solve it, that it doesn't stop if a file is empty?

```
Sub MergeTxtFiles()
    Dim fso As Object, txt As Object, strTxt As String
    Dim strParentFldr As String, strFile As String
    Dim iFreeFile As Integer, strOutPutFile As String

    KillProperly "D:\users\gf05856\Documents\TEst\RVA002ALL.txt"
    Call DeleteLine1
    Call DeleteLine2

    strOutPutFile = "D:\users\gf05856\Documents\TEst\RVA002ALL.txt"
    strParentFldr = "D:\users\gf05856\Documents\TEst"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    strFile = Dir(strParentFldr & "\Register van aankomst 002*.txt")

    If Len(strFile) > 0 Then
        Do
            Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile(strParentFldr & "\" & strFile)
            strTxt = strTxt & txt.ReadAll
            strFile = Dir
        Loop Until Len(strFile) = 0
        If Left(strTxt, 2) = vbCrLf Then strTxt = Mid(strTxt, 2)
    End If

    iFreeFile = FreeFile

    Open strOutPutFile For Output As #iFreeFile
    Print #iFreeFile, strTxt
    Close #iFreeFile

    Set txt = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub KillProperly(Killfile As String)
    If Len(Dir$(Killfile)) > 0 Then
        SetAttr Killfile, vbNormal
        Kill Killfile
    End If
End Sub

Sub DeleteLine1()
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\users\gf05856\Documents\TEst\Register van aankomst 002 - D (Histo).txt", ForReading)

    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine
        If InStr(strLine, "CLIFOUPAYCODE") = 0 Then
            strNewContents = strNewContents & strLine & vbCrLf
        End If
    Loop

    objFile.Close
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\users\gf05856\Documents\TEst\Register van aankomst 002 - D (Histo).txt", ForWriting)

    objFile.Write strNewContents
    objFile.Close
End Sub

Sub DeleteLine2()
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\users\gf05856\Documents\TEst\Register van aankomst 002 - D.txt", ForReading)

    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine
        If InStr(strLine, "CLIFOUPAYCODE") = 0 Then
            strNewContents = strNewContents & strLine & vbCrLf
        End If
    Loop

    objFile.Close
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\users\gf05856\Documents\TEst\Register van aankomst 002 - D.txt", ForWriting)

    objFile.Write strNewContents
    objFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't simply do `copy a.txt + b.txt + c.txt output.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

.ReadAll() fails on empty/zero length/size files:

```
>> WScript.Echo oFS.GetFile("x").Size
>> Set f = oFS.OpenTextFile("x")
>> s = f.ReadAll()
>>
0
Error Number:       62
Error Description:  Eingabe hinter Dateiende.
>>
```

So you should check the .Size to determine whether the file should be opened at all.

(BTW: What's the real world problem you try to solve?)